# Couchdb Authentication / Authorisation

Tags: couchdb

In couchdb if a database is secured, it redirects to "/_utils/session.html " based on "authentication_redirect" configuration setting.

If I have few databases like db1, db2, etc  what I want is couchdb to redirect to /db1/logon.html for db1 & /db2/logon.html for db2, etc..

Is it possible to make couchdb redirect to specific logon file based on database being accessed?

Answer (score 7):

You can pass a ?fail= parameter. to tell couchdb where to send a user that fails authentication. Futon uses it like this;

Successful auth;

```
curl -sv 'localhost:5984/_session?next=/foo&fail=/bar' -d 'name=foo&password=bar'

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Location: http://localhost:5984/foo
{"ok":true,"name":null,"roles":["_admin"]}
```

Failed auth;

```
curl -Haccept:text/html -sv 'localhost:5984/_session?next=/foo&fail=/bar' -d 'name=foo&password=baz'
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Location: http://localhost:5984/bar
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this is to use rewrites like:

```
{from: '/db1/*', to: '../../../db1/*'},
{from: '/db2/*', to: '../../../db2/*'}
```

on your main db call it main being served from localhost:5984.

Config needed is as follows in futon

```
httpd secure_rewrites false
vhosts localhost:5984 /main/_design/edit/_rewrite
```

The only issue with this is that you will have to turn secure_rewrites off which may mess up your security.

This is untested, but should be darn close.